# Barrier strip for power distribution

Tags: power-engineering

I'm working on a project where I need to supply power to multiple strings of LEDs, operating at 12VDC, with a max current draw of 20mA per string.

What I'm looking for a quick and easy way to connect multiple strings to one central power source.  The LED strings are terminated to spade lugs, and something like [this](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/38720-0212/WM5727-ND/362444) would be perfect.  The only problem is that the individual terminals aren't tied together in the example above.  Basically, I need a bus bar with approximately 10 screw terminals for spade lugs, used for power distribution.  It's not a high voltage/current/power application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look for a "power distribution block" instead of a "terminal block" or "barrier strip." Making your own is also quite feasible, per @srlm.

Comment: What about this http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/544360375/HC_030_screw_ground_terminal_block.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If screw-down commoned connection points are what you want....

[image]

These can be found [here](http://www.newmarpower.com/Terminal_Strips_Bus_Bars/Terminal_Strips_Bus_Bars.html)

[image]

These can be found [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10-Gang-Terminal-Block-Common-Bus-Bar-with-Brass-Terminals-for-Boats-/120870307317)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to build your own. Buy a metal strip from a hardware store and drill a hole in it every 1/4". Then you can use 1/2" bolts (I'd go with #8 sized) with a nut to attach your lugs to the bar.